# Inverse function theorem proof query

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Please see for the proof, on page 2: http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~nwallach/inverse[1].pdf

I don't understand the statement of "the theorem is equally true or falose for both $L^{-1} \circ f$ and $f$ simultaneously, hence we porve it when $L = I$." I don't follow how the author concluded this from the previous lines - could someone please explain.

Answer (score 1):

Because $L^{-1}$ is an invertible linear map, the chain rule tells us that $D(L^{-1}\circ f)(a) = L^{-1}\circ Df(a)$ and so $Df(a)$ is invertible if and only if $D(L^{-1}\circ f)(a)$ is invertible. On the other end of the theorem, if we prove that $L^{-1}\circ f$ has a local inverse $g$, then $L\circ g$ will be a local inverse of $f$.